# static variable php test functionality don't understand error mechanism

Tags: php

I'm testing functionality of an variable..$age = 30. I put the variable in out of function body:the output is ok , but when i put the variable before echo in the function..and after echo ..throw error.. why? I want to understand the error mechanism.
First example:

```
<?php
function birthday(){
    static $age = 0;

    $age = $age + 1;
    $age = 30; 
    echo "Birthday number $age <br/>";

}

birthday();
birthday();
birthday();

echo "Age: $age<br/>";

?>
Output:Birthday number 30
       Birthday number 30
       Birthday number 30

Notice: Undefined variable: age in C:\xampp\htdocs\series\exercitii_php\variabila_statica.php on line 18
Age: 
Why?

second example:
<?php
function birthday(){
    static $age = 0;

    $age = $age + 1;

    echo "Birthday number $age <br/>";
   $age = 30; 
}



birthday();
birthday();
birthday();


echo "Age: $age<br/>";

?>
Output: Birthday number 1
        Birthday number 31
        Birthday number 31

Notice: Undefined variable: age in C:\xampp\htdocs\series\exercitii_php\variabila_statica.php on line 18
Age:
```

Please give me your explanation so I can understand.

Comment: Because your `$age` is in the scope of your function. Is it a class or what?

Comment: this is because you are calling the variable $age outiside the function .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
function birthday() {
    static $age = null;
    if (empty($age)) {
        $age = 30;
    } else {
        $age = $age + 1;
    }
    echo "Birthday number $age <br/>";
}

birthday();
birthday();
birthday();
```

Note: you can not access `$age` in the global scope, because it's in the function scope.

If you want it to use as `global` then you can not use it as static, but this is the worst option i think:

```
global $age;

function birthday() {
    global $age;
    if (empty($age)) {
        $age = 30;
    } else {
        $age = $age + 1;
    }
    echo "Birthday number $age <br/>";
}

birthday();
birthday();
birthday();
echo $age;
```

Comment: Cannot be overriden static variable?..how to use on my example?

Comment: I've edited my code. But warning. this way you can always overwrite the `$age` variable. Avoid to use `global` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$age` variable is local to your `birthday` method/function, therefore, cannot be used outside the scope of that method. In order to use it everywhere within a script, you'd either have to make it global to the script, or put it inside a class, with getters/setters, or make it public (but that's really dirty!).

More info can be found here about variable scope: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: But where can i put the global keyward to work? canot be overriden the static variable?

Comment: Why do you insist on using a static variable? They're useful sometimes, but usually frowned upon.

Comment: Only i test functionality to understand ..how it action.